# How do I add a section to my app config

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

I have an automatic update app that will update my clients application. The config file will have some minor additions between upgrades. Usually the changes are the addition of keys. Since I cannot upgrade a config file with the updater I have to add the new keys pragmatically. This is the easy part.

```
  var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                config.AppSettings.Settings["key].Value = "value";
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

I now have a new section that needs to be added to the config file and I do not know how to add it.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
      <client configSource="Config\clients.config"/>
    <bindings configSource="Config\bindings.config"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Above is what I need to add to the config file. How can I do this with the ConfiguationManager? I can not just open the xml up using an xml reader and add the section as I am sure it would run into issues with the app already using it, and permissions, as it is installed in the programs directory.

I would appreciate any help here.
Thank you,

Comment: Have a look at this implementation: [Change .config File at Runtime C# Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878910/Change-config-File-at-Runtime-Csharp-Code), the source code for this is on [GitHub](https://github.com/angelovstanton/AANGELOV/tree/master/ConfigModificator/CSharp)

Comment: .net config is not mean to be dynamically change. if ur sys need such feature, it's better u just implement ur own config mechanism, so u won't have concern with .net config constraints.